# Can't run snap apps

Tags: snap, 22.10, dbus

I'm running Ubuntu 22.10 and I'm having an issue where if I run this command in my .xinitrc file snap apps aren't able to run.

```
exec dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session dwm
```

However, if I just run `exec dwm` there isn't an issue, but I really need the dbus command. This is what I get when I try to run any snap app from the terminal

```
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope is not a snap cgroup
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem running snaps, but it's a problem with some other thing you're trying to do.  But you didn't actually tell us what that is. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need this line?

Comment: @Nmath I need the dbus line because I'm using a command line tool called playerctl for my media control functionality in dwm and it doesn't work without me running dbus at startup